# I can't allocate memory to my char pointer

Tags: c++, cstring

I am trying to just allocate memory to char pointer (its supposed to store hex values later)
As soon as i run this code the program crashes.
(I have to use C-String)

```
int main() {
    char *c = (char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)*2);
}
```

I see this all over the internet as example, but it fails on my machine. Why?

Comment: Why malloc( which is C ) and not new ( which is C++ )

Comment: what would that look like?

Comment: How does it chash? It is a compiler error?

Comment: You mean to tell us that this code above is the sole content of your main function?

Comment: well its just a test programm to make sure that this is the exact problem.

Comment: Take a look here : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: http://ideone.com/gjbMBn it did not crash

Comment: This code does not and will not crash.

Comment: Allocating a C-string using the size of `unsigned int` seems particularly strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay the solution was as easy as the question was supposed to be...
I did not see that the .exe file could not be generated and I was therefore running an old .exe file compiled 1hour ago...

Comment: Upboated for the laugh.

Answer (score 1):

Malloc is C, you're trying to do C++.

I would simply do this:

```
char *c;
c=new char[Max_Size];
```

Obviously Max_Size would be the size of your intended array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for malloc
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *c = (char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)*2); //It's work

    printf("%d",sizeof(c));

    return 0; // required
}
```

Comment: `return 0;` isn't required.

Comment: In theory, if you didn't include `stdlib.h` then it wouldn't compile, as C++ (and also C99) requires functions to be declared before they are used.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say what you mean saying that it fails. In any case you have to include header `<stdlib.h>`

if the program is written in C or `<cstdlib>` if the program is written in C++.

C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *c = (char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)*2);
    free( c );
}
```

And in any case you should present a code that allows to reproduce the situation. I think that the problem is not in this code but somewhere else where you overwrite memory. The code you showed I think is irrelevant.

Comment: He did mention what fail means. He said the "program crashes"

Comment: @Vishal it can mean anything. I am not a telepathist.